# Problem with jQuery iframe resizing in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I am using this snippet of code to dynamically resize an iframe (same domain) within a page:

```
function setHeight() {
        $("#myframe").height($("#myframe").contents().find("html").height());
    }
```

It works in Chrome, FF, and Safari, but not in IE8.  Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Thanks.

Edit: Should mention that I am calling this function from an iframe onload event.

Comment: Could you put your code up at http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: You can view the code at http://zoomout.in/worldwide-climate-search/

Comment: have you solved this one? i have the same problem

Comment: What's the DOCTYPE of the document in the iframe? Also, I've used body rather than html when I've done iframe resizing previously, might be worth a go...

Answer (score 0):

I did this in jsfiddle.net so here's a link if you want to test it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/4LQFc/5/

Here's the rundown:

This is your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="div_loaded">loaded div</div>
    <p id="get_dimentions"></p>
    <iframe src="" id="iframetosize"></iframe>
</body>
</html>​
```

Some optional CSS...for demo purposes:

```
p { 
          margin:10px;
          padding:5px;
          border:2px solid #666;
} 
#div_loaded { 
          position:relative;
          display:block;
          margin:10px;
          padding:5px;
          border:2px solid #666;
          height:30%; 
          width:30%;
} 
#iframetosize {
          margin:10px;
          padding:5px;
          background-color:#000; 
          color:#fff;
}​
```

This is the jQuery (ugly, but works):

```
var getsize = $("#div_loaded");
$("#get_dimentions").text( "Width: " + getsize.outerWidth() + " , Height: " + getsize.outerWidth(true) );
var sizewidth = getsize.outerWidth();
var sizeheight = getsize.outerHeight();
$("#iframetosize").css('height',sizeheight); 
$("#iframetosize").css('width',sizewidth);
```

Let me know if this helps..IE has (as we all know) some real problems. The .css will help if can use it. You may have to play with CSS a little as well as outerWidth(true) vs ().